# Where can I find the number of banks by country?

Tags: data-request, global, bank

Seeking an open dataset listing the number of banking institutions that exist, and the country/countries they exist in?

Answer (score 2):

**[Commercial bank branches (per 100,000 adults)](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/FB.CBK.BRCH.P5)**

Data is collected by the International Monetary Fund, Financial Access Survey. Data has a [friendly license](http://data.worldbank.org/summary-terms-of-use).

On the right you will see a big DOWNLOAD button (CSV, XML or XLS)

[image]

[image]

---

If, for some reason, you don't want the data per capita, but instead total bank branches, then you can use this data set to get the population of each country.

**[Population, total](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SP.POP.TOTL)**

Answer (score 2):

If you want the number of bank "companies" per countries, then you can harvest [this data from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Lists_of_banks_by_country)

On the left menu-bar of every Wikipedia page is a link to "[Wikidata Item](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q7092370)". You can then use a Wikidata query tool to [programmatically collect the data](https://query.wikidata.org/). See other questsions or do an internet search about Wikidata or SPARQL query language.

---

Or, use this website **[Banks by country](https://thebanks.eu/banks-by-country)** for EU banks (including offshore territories).

[image]